# Synonym/more sophisticated term for free-flowing

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for an apt, or rather, a more sophisticated description for my cacographic handwriting style.

The term free-flowing is strictly accurate. However, I am looking for a adjective or term that connotes a uniformed mess: if possible, with a touch of grace applied. I recall having come across a word with a similar definition, suffixed by -iform, although I have not been able to remember or find this word again.

All those's who have helped or have tried, I thank you in advance.

P.s I am new to posting to English stack exchange so please forgive any communal  faux pas i may commit.

Comment: Flourish style? : embellished writing, characters, etc, with ornamental strokes.

Comment: @Josh61 "Flourish" is a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: Is "uniformed mess" a typo?

Comment: @argurar no it is not a typo. Uniformed mess, meaning messy in a consistent way or style. Sorry for any mix-up, and Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: You might consider "cuneiform-like".  (And "uniformed mess" is at least an odd construction.  Your handwriting might be a "uniform mess", but "uniformed" implies that it's dressed in a (military?) uniform.)

Answer (score -1):

I can't imagine this word would have any connotation of grace whatsoever, but a word ending in `-iform` that could be applied to terrible handwriting might be **epileptiform**.

> [epileptiform](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epileptiform) (adj.) - resembling that of epilepsy

Comment: And I was downvoted because...?

Answer (score -1):

Could 'fluid' work?

> : having or showing a smooth and easy style http://i.word.com/idictionary/fluid

Comment: "Fluid" fits "free flowing", but not "cacographic".  But, to use a different liquid metaphor, it might be described as "turbulent".